# Would like to map <S-j> to scroll previous colon commands

Tags: vim

I'm trying to map `<S-j>` to scroll previous colon commands. So `<S-j>` instead of `:` and `<Up>`.

```
nnoremap <S-j> :<Up>
```

Problem with this bind is that scrolling the 2nd last colon command is actually `:<Up><Up>`, but if you press `<S-j>` twice you get `:<Up>:<Up>` instead.

How do I map it properly so that it outputs `:<Up>` if not in command bar and just `<Up>`, if command bar has text already inside

Comment: `<S-j>` you meant `shift-J` ? how do you do join then?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your behavior. If I press `<S-j>` (which by the way is just a convoluted way to say `J`) twice, I get the previous command-line plus the literal letter `J`. Your command is defined for *normal mode*; due to the `:` in the right-hand side it will end in *command-line mode*. `J` = `<S-j>` is *not* mapped there (at least not by `:nnoremap`).

In order to be able to repeat `J`, you'd have to define an additional mapping for command-line mode:

```
:cnoremap <S-j> <Up>
```

This leaves out the `:`, as you're already in the command-line.

However, I would not recommend this, as it will leave you unable to directly type a capital J (you can still type it via `<C-v>J`, or as you like to say, `<C-v><S-j>`). You'd better switch to a mapping that uses a non-printable character (e.g. `<C-j>`).

Comment: I see. That makes complete sense, thanks for clarifying.